# How to display the thumbnails of the products in the cart - Magento

Tags: php, image, magento, cart

I have been trying to work this out for the past hour. Hope you guys can help. I am working on a magento website 1.9.0.1 and trying to display the products currently in the cart as a widget elsewhere. I am able to display the Product Name, Price, qty and the grad total. However I can not get the product image to display. Instead of the product image the default magento placeholder image is displayed.

This is the code block that i am working with :

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) { ?>
<div class="cart-single">
    <div class="cart-content-image">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="cart-content-details">
        <?php 
            $maxLength = 50;
            $productName = $item->getName();
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-short">'.substr($productName, 0, $maxLength).'...</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-full">'.$item->getName().'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-price">'. $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($item->getPrice(), 2).'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-qty">Qty : '. $item->getQty().'</div>'; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

The problem I am having is on this line:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" />
```

I have searched for the past hour, and tried different solutions, but couldn't get them to work, so I thought I'd display the code in question.

Help and advise appreciated. Thanks

Modified Code

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) { ?>
<div class="cart-single">
    <div class="cart-content-image">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="cart-content-details">
        <?php 
            $maxLength = 50;
            $productName = $item->getName();
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-short">'.substr($productName, 0, $maxLength).'...</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-full">'.$item->getName().'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-price">'. $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($item->getPrice(), 2).'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-qty">Qty : '. $item->getQty().'</div>'; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got this to work. Did more look around on the net and thanks to @Robbie Averill for giving me some ideas. The problem I was having is that the images I needed to display were of products already in the cart so using:

```
$item->getProduct
```

was not exactly returning the URL of the images, just giving me blank hence the default magento thumbnails. So I managed to get a workaround this, may not be the best way to do it but it works. For all the in cart product details I used:

```
$quote->getItemsCollection() as $item
```

This allowed me to get the product name, price and qty. But to get the image I had to get the Product ID and use that to get the Thumbnail. As all products in the store were configurable products I had to add 2 more lines to find the parent ID and then use that for the thumbnail. Normally you'd just set it on the admin end to use parent image, but wasn't working for this widget and I wasn't in the right mind to solve that out right now. So just entered the code to find the parent ID. Anyway code block is below just in case anybody comes across this issue and need something to build upon.

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) { ?>
<div class="cart-single">
    <div class="cart-content-image">
    <?php 
    $conid = $item->getProductId();
    $simpleProductId = $conid;
    $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="cart-content-details">
        <?php 
            $maxLength = 50;
            $productName = $item->getName();
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-short">'.substr($productName, 0, $maxLength).'...</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-name-full">'.$item->getName().'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-price">'. $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($item->getPrice(), 2).'</div>';
            echo '<div class="cart-content-qty">Qty : '. $item->getQty().'</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `...->init($item->getProduct(), 'image')...` as the product is a component of the cart item (`$item`) - see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getProduct()`.

The `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init()` method expects an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, but you'd be passing in the cart item which is a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` (or `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`):

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
/**
 * Initialize Helper to work with Image
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param string $attributeName
 * @param mixed $imageFile
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Adjusted code should work:

```
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) { ?>
<div class="cart-single">
    <div class="cart-content-image">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>" />
    </div>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie. I have updated my code with your updated line. However, still showing the thumbnail. I have update first post with the modified code exactly as entered. please let me know if i have missed something or if I need to add a line or two. Thanks for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @AlphaOne - try using `thumbnail` instead of `image`, i.e. `init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')`

Comment: Just been tried it with 'thumbnail' still showing me the same. When looking at the processed code in html. It seems the image for the product in the cart is not being called for. Or if it is not the correct path. Seems to just load placeholder image.

Comment: Sounds fishy to me @AlphaOne. Try using this in your root directory to ensure that your product image will load when you test it manually: http://pastebin.com/PDmNkYpv - also sanity check that your product actually has images, etc etc ;)

Comment: Thanks that's loading fine as I entered the SKU for a product. What I don't understand is that images are loading in a header drop down cart, the cart page. But when trying it on this code block it;s not working. I want to display this block as a order summary, but not exactly on the sidebar hence me needing this code block to work so i can just drop where i need it to work. Apart from that these are configurable products, but I have tried setting the admin side to use parent image as well as product image. Still no joy. Anyway I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey @AlphaOne - if I were you I'd do a `var_dump(get_class($item))` and check what the class instance is, then do the same on `$item->getProduct()`.